# about Date operation no correct problem in google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

```js
  var lastrow = SS.getLastRow()
  var lastday = SS.getRange("A"+ lastrow).getValue(); //Thu Dec 31 11:00:00 GMT-05:00 2009 = 2010-01-01 (GMT +8)
  var today = SS.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var diffInDays = Math.floor((today-lastday)/(24*3600*1000));

  //Creat DateAr |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
  Logger.log(diffInDays)
  var AddingAr =[]
  for (var i = 1; i < diffInDays ; i = i + 1) {

    var d_date = new Date();
    d_date = d_date.setDate(lastday.getDate()+ i )
    var d_dateString = Utilities.formatDate( new Date(d_date) , "GMT+8", "yyyy-MM-dd")
    AddingAr.push([d_dateString])
    Logger.log("lastday: "+ lastday+" +i:" +i + " =d_date: "+ d_date +" = " + d_dateString)

  }

  Logger.log(AddingAr)
  Logger.log(AddingAr.length)
  SS.getRange(lastrow + 1, 1,AddingAr.length).setValues(AddingAr)
```

as seem , //Thu Dec 31 11:00:00 GMT-05:00 2009 = 2010-01-01 (GMT +8)
d_date = d_date.setDate(lastday.getDate()+ i ) //in for loop

2010-01-01 + 1 should be 2010-01-02 log:2022-09-02
2010-01-01 + 2 should be 2010-01-03

i have no idea why
2010-01-01 + 1 is 2022-09-02

```js
Log:

lastday: Thu Dec 31 2009 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) +i:1 =d_date: 1662023267434 = 2022-09-01
下午5:07:47   資訊  lastday: Thu Dec 31 2009 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) +i:2 =d_date: 1662109667441 = 2022-09-02
下午5:07:47   資訊  lastday: Thu Dec 31 2009 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) +i:3 =d_date: 1662196067443 = 2022-09-03
下午5:07:47   資訊  lastday: Thu Dec 31 2009 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) +i:4 =d_date: 1662282467445 = 2022-09-04
下午5:07:47   資訊  lastday: Thu Dec 31 2009 11:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) +i:5 =d_date: 1662368867447 = 2022-09-05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The javascript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object only refers to the day of the month, not the whole date

- [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) does not create an empty date object, but it creates the date of today including the time in hours, minutes and seconds.
- If you execute `console.log(new Date())` **today**, it will result in something like `Tue Aug 08 2022 07:44:012 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`
- Then, for example  `console.log(new Date().setDate(10))` will result in `Tue Aug 10 2022 07:44:012 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`
- What you want instead is to create a date object from your existing timestamp:
  `var d_date = new Date(lastday);` instead of `var d_date = new Date();`
- Then, the rest of your code will work - if `lastday` is a valid date object
- For better understanding

```
function myTestFunction(){
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastrow = SS.getLastRow()
  var lastday = SS.getRange("A"+ lastrow).getValue();
  var d_date = new Date(lastday);
  console.log(d_date);
  console.log(d_date.setDate(10));
}
```